# Converting KeyPair to RSAKey

Tags: java, cryptography, rsa, bouncycastle, jce

I'm trying to find out the bitlength of a [KeyPair](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/KeyPair.html). While looking around for solutions on how to go about doing this, I came across the following code snippet.

```
public boolean checkKey(RSAKey key) {
    if ( key.getModulus().bitLength() == 1024 )
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The input that I am expecting is a "KeyPair". Could someone point me towards documentation that does either :-

1. Demonstrate how to convert a KeyPair to an [RSAKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/security/interfaces/RSAKey.html)
2. OR Demonstrate how to calculate the bit length of a KeyPair

Answer (score 2):

This should do it for an RSA key (assuming `keyPair` is a `KeyPair` instance):

```
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

if (publicKey instanceof RSAPublicKey) {
  return ((RSAPublicKey) publicKey).getModulus().bitLength();
}
```

If you need to check other keys types, just check the docs and code accordingly, e.g.:

```
if (publicKey instanceof DSAPublicKey) {
  return ((DSAPublicKey) publicKey).getY().bitLength();
}
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an error that states "inconvertible types"

Comment: I get "Incompatible conditional operand types KeyPair and RSAPublicKey" for the first and "Cannot cast from KeyPair to Public Key" on the second line.

Comment: @uki I've tested the code works, so there must be an error in how you've implemented it. Please edit your question to show me how you've tried to use my code sample.